# What does it mean that Bruno can hit $6\,\rm{kN}$?

Tags: forces

Is it the momentum?

But momentum is $\rm{Ns}$, not $\rm{N}$.

http://www.skepticforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=14624

> I'm not sure that 3,430 N is necessarily beyond human capability.
>   Boxer Frank Bruno's punch was in excess of 6,000 N.

Unit of momentum is $\rm{Ns}$, not $\rm{N}$.

Does it mean that Frank Bruno punch can excert force of $6\,\rm{kN}$?

[image]

That means with one hand, he can excert force enough to lift $.6$ tons of weight?

The problem with this interpretation is that the amount of force yielded by a hand is very dependent on how the momentum of the punch distributed through time. An iron hand would generate huge force while a rubber gloves would generate a very low force even though the momentum is the same.

Okay, back to the question. What does it mean anyway by a $6\,\rm{kN}$ punch force?

Comment: Here is the original Frank Bruno study in [PDF](http://europepmc.org/articles/PMC1419171/pdf/bmjcred00479-0016.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

You are right, Newton is the unit of force, not momentum. You also correctly identified the problem: the relevant quantity to judge how severe a punch by Bruno would be is the momentum transferred onto yourself, which is sometimes referred to as **impulse**. It is also true that 6 kN correspond to the weight of 600 kg on Earth. The crucial point is that you would have to maintain that force over some time to counter gravity. Frank Bruno could hardly stop a car from falling onto himself single-handedly.

Therefore, my understanding is that you are absolutely right and whoever measures punch forces either doesn't know his physics or would have to apply a standardized test with constant impact time.

Comment: Jonas, this isn't true, or at least is not wholly true. If you transferred momentum to my head by pressing gently on it for a long time I probably wouldn't mind. On the other hand if you transferred the momentum using a baseball bat that would sting! The peak force clearly is important.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. I still think that impulse is the relevant quantity once the time scale is short enough that the victim has not enough time to pick up speed and "evade" the punch.

Comment: Also, in terms of physical severity, the impact area would also be important. Obviously, it's worse when he's wearing knuckledusters.

Comment: I would think that the most relevant quantity would be average power over the duration of the punch.  Damage to the skin/bones/etc will be governed by how much energy you deliver to break chemical bonds, fundamentally.  It's still not perfect, because so much depends on the geometry of the situation, and the particulars of how contact is made, but as a first approximation, I think the question is one of power delivered.

I think they cite peak power just because of how ridiculously high the nubmers seem, especially when interpreted by lifting--it makes the boxer seem stronger citing force.